# How to access message of AlertDialog built by AlertDialog.Builder?

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have this AlertDialog and AlertDialog.Builder:

```
    String message = "A message";
    AlertDialog.Builder dBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dBuilder.setMessage(message);
    ....
    AlertDialog myDialog = dBuilder.create();
```

Now I am writing a unit test and need to test the message of the dialog. How can I access that message?

Comment: What do you mean by `test the message of dialog` ?

Comment: test if the message equals a particular string

Comment: What is your scenario? Why do you want to do that?

Comment: the dialog displays an error message with error code. I need to test if it is displaying the correct error code.

Comment: It's impossible to guess your problem from your description mate

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: in what way is it  unclear?

Answer (score 8):

Give this a shot. Instead of initializing myDialog with dBuilder.create(), use the construction of the builder:

```
String message = "A message";
AlertDialog.Builder dBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
AlertDialog myDialog = dBuilder
              .setMessage(message)
              .show();
TextView messageTextView = (TextView)myDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
String dialogMessage = messageTextView.getText();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
TextView textView = (TextView)myDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
Log.e("TEST", ""+textView.getText());
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the actual question in a test-friendly way that does not screw up the design. Now, if Android could follow the rule "every setter has a getter, even if production code doesn't need one"?

Answer (score -1):

Use a view to define a TextView and add the view inside the AlertDialog.Builder.

So now when you want to test the String inside the AlertDialog, just access it

`view.textView.getText().toString();`

Comment: Then debug the source code on an emulator and add a breakpoint after the `String message = "message";` statement