# Listening For Touch In Padding Area Between Elements of An AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

I have onTouchListeners for the (custom) title area and for the message area of my AlertDialog.

**I'm trying to have my dialog set up in such a way that the user can mindlessly tap in the top right 1/4th of the AlertDialog to toggle the whether background music plays or not since just having the speaker as the tappable area would result in too small of a hit box/area.**

**My problem is: the area in between the message and title marked in red isn't handling ontouchlistener events**

Most people would suggest creating a custom dialog, but the thing is I really like the way this dialog looks (it has a very stock material design aesthetic) and already jumped through a lot of hoops to get it to look exactly the way I like (drawing leaderboard over an invisible neutral button, custom title area). I don't want to make a custom dialog unless I can make it look absolutely identical to what I have now (so hard to mimic the look of stock material dialogs, trust me i've tried and did a lot of research/wasted a lot of time trying that).

I'm assuming the on touch events for the custom title area and message area don't encompass or account for the margins or padding in between.

Pardon the disgusting code!! I'm just trying to hack everything together and tidy it up later.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Screenshot]

**The linear layout for my custom title area of the alertdialog**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="0px"
    android:paddingTop="0px"
    android:paddingLeft="0px"
    android:paddingRight="0px"
    android:paddingBottom="0px" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/st"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_pause"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leaderboard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#800080"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.DialogWindowTitle"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="18dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Paused"

        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/soundtoggle"
        style="?android:attr/panelTextAppearance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="?android:dialogPreferredPadding"
        android:gravity="right"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**My android code**

```
AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(AndroidLauncher.this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog))
                        .setMessage(msg)
                        .setCustomTitle(myLayout)
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setNegativeButton("End Game", new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                pauseInterface.end();
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNeutralButton("   ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                //startSignInIntent();
                                showLeaderboard();
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        })
                        .setPositiveButton("Resume", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                pauseInterface.resume();
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });


                alertDialog = ad.create();

                int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android");
                if (titleId > 0) {
                    TextView dialogTitle = (TextView) alertDialog.findViewById(titleId);

                }

                alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                        Button button = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
                        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_leaderboard);
                        drawable.setBounds((int) 0,
                                0, (int) (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() * 1),
                                drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
                        button.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, null, null, null);
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.show();
                final ImageView soundToggle = (ImageView) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.soundtoggle);
                if (tetrisgame.getMusicState()) {
                    if (tetrisgame.getMusicState()) {
                        soundToggle.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.music_on, getApplicationContext().getTheme()));

                    } else {
                        soundToggle.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.music_off, getApplicationContext().getTheme()));
                    }
                    TextView tv = (TextView) alertDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                    tv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent m) {

                            if (m.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && (m.getX() >= (v.getRight() - (v.getWidth() / 4)))) {
                                Log.println(Log.ERROR, "Ken", "Popular Pothead");
                                if (tetrisgame.toggleMusic()) {
                                    String uri = "@drawable/music_on";  // where myresource (without the extension) is the file

                                    int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());


                                    Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
                                    soundToggle.setImageDrawable(res);
//                            soundToggle.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.music_off, alertDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message).getTheme()));

                                } else {
                                    soundToggle.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.music_off, null));

                                }

                            }
                            return true;
                        }

                    });

                    final LinearLayout as = (LinearLayout) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.st);
                    as.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent m) {

                            if (m.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                                Log.println(Log.ERROR, "Ken", "Tweed");
                                if (tetrisgame.toggleMusic()) {
                                    String uri = "@drawable/music_on";  // where myresource (without the extension) is the file

                                    int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());


                                    Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
                                    soundToggle.setImageDrawable(res);
//                            soundToggle.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.music_off, alertDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message).getTheme()));

                                } else {
                                    soundToggle.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.music_off, null));

                                }
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: One thing, i dont see "message" id in your layout for a textview. Another is maybe your linear layout ontouchlistener is messing up your other listener since it pertains to the whole layout. You should put some logs into your listeners to see what exactly is firing and go from there

Comment: message.id is a preset AlertDialog android thing that can't be changed and wasn't created by me. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582960/how-to-access-message-of-alertdialog-built-by-alertdialog-builder

Comment: ill mess around with logging and testing more stuff. Notice the Log.println statements I left in the code from when I was testing it before

Comment: i can confirm that the issue is still as stands and that the two listeners aren't interfering or cause two event fires on one tap due to overlap