# How do I create a custom dialog that looks identical to an alertdialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, ontouchlistener

How do I create a custom dialog that looks identical to a material light alertdialog (as far as aesthetics go, down to every possible padding, font, color, etc). I want my app to have a super "stock" material feel.

The only reason I need to make my own dialog as opposed to using an alertdialog is because of athe limitation that you can't have an ontouchlistener for the entire alertdialog it's self

see for more clarification on the limitation -> [Listening For Touch In Padding Area Between Elements of An AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48122132/getting-touch-input-listening-for-touch-from-padding-between-elements-of-an-al))

Comment: If identical then why not use `AlertDialog`?

Comment: Hit post too early. Just edited

Comment: I do not think  there is a significance of onTouch . Because Alert dialog shows a center window. Can you pls explain what exactly you want to achieve with some images. and what the requirement for onTouch in Dialog .

Comment: [Explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmitf.png)

Comment: I want to be able to just get an ontouchlistener set up for the whole dialog, if possible, so I can process when a user taps in the top right-ish area

Comment: Which would let me avoid the problem of trying to imitate a stock alertdialog altogether

Comment: Ok . I do not know the exact solution but can start with a Dialog with  CardView(withou elevation) and Ripple effects at very basic . You can also take reference at `AlertDialog` class of android .

Comment: This may help you. https://material.io/guidelines/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-specs